# Is there any way to get an array containing un-instantiated prefabs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a folder, Items, that contains prefabs with the class attached, what I want to do is make an array full of these prefabs in order to compare their ID numbers, a string inside the item class, with the ID numbers from a database  to put these prefabs into an inventory array, I hope this is enough detail.

Comment: Please show us your existing attempt to try and do this yourself.

Comment: As @mjwills said. Also, that code might clarify what this question is about, since it is totally unclear to me what you want to achieve.

Comment: What we call `Instantiate` is just a way to make a copy of a prefab, there are no special difference between a prefab and its instantiated Object.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you probably need.

```
public List<GameObject> prefabsWithClassOnThem;

public GameObject CheckTheID(string ID)
{
    foreach (GameObject go in prefabsWithClassOnThem)
    {
        if(go.GetComponent<ItemClass>().getID() == ID){
            return go;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

prefabsWithClassOnThem - the name speaks for itself. It is the list of prefabs you will have to put manually into the list. Then you add your script to a script manager (or any object you feel like) this is how it will look like:
[image]

Click on the arrow, write in wanted size and put all the prefabs manually.

[image]

CheckTheID - method, which will check for a prefab with the ID you give for this method.

ItemClass - the class, you were mentioning in your question. The class which holds the ID of prefab, and has method GetID().

You will want to call this method in your addToInventory method or something like this.

If you want to check if object was instantiated before, just create additional boolean parameter in ItemClass which will hold true if it was instantiated (you will have to change it for the first time you instantiate one of the prefabs).
Every time you want to create unique item, just check the boolean and thats pretty much it.

Sorry for messy language.